# How to retrieve number of decimals for custom token (not DOT)?

Tags: polkadot-js, chainspec, token

How to retrieve number of decimals for custom token (not DOT)?

`api.registry.chainDecimals` is for DOT.  I need to retrieve it for a custom token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the asset metadata like this:

```js
let asset = await api.query.assets.metadata(0 /* Asset Id */);
console.log("Asset has", asset.decimals, "decimals");
```